# Using DateTime library in Remix to Convert Timestamp to DateTime format

Tags: timestamp, solidity, smartcontracts, unix-timestamp, remix

If anyone is familiar with importing a library into Remix, then using it, maybe you can help. What i am doing pertains to this library...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@quant-finance/solidity-datetime?activeTab=explore

The steps i took to import this and use this library in remix with my existing contract are as follows...

1. I went to the "code" tab on that link. Saw... DateTime.sol contract. I copied and pasted the entire contract into a file called... DateTime.sol in my folder in Remix.
   Now I have my original contract file called Escrow.sol and DateTime.sol both in my Folder in Remix.
2. In my main contract I import the DateTime.sol library at the top of my Escrow.sol file like this...

   ```
   import "./DateTime.sol";
   ```
3. Lastly I put the function I want from the DateTime.sol contract into my Escrow contract like this...

   ```
   function timestampToDateTime(uint timestamp) public pure returns (uint year, uint month, uint day, uint hour, uint minute, uint second) {
         return (year, month, day, hour, minute, second); 
   }
   ```
4. I compile both contracts now, deploy, and now in Escrow.sol (my main contract, not the library), I test the function. I put a timestamp in the function box in remix but it doesn't convert. It shows all 0's for the year, month, day.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am basically just copying and pasting the entire library as a separate contract in Remix, importing the library into my main contract, and then trying to use one of the library functions in my main contract (copy and pasting the one function i need from the library into my main contract) but it doesn't work. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i just figured it out. For anyone who sees this, the function in my main contract needed to be as follows as i needed to call the other contract function like this...

`function convertTimstamp(uint timestamp) public pure returns (uint year, uint month, uint day, uint hour, uint minute, uint second) { return DateTime.timestampToDateTime(timestamp);`